# How to use codeigniter routes on a procedural style PHP website with a codeigniter folder structure?

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, routes, procedural

I have a website built with a folder structure exactly like code igniter which has this folders:

- app (controllers/core/helpers/libraries/models/views/) etc.
- assets
- files
- system (core/database/fonts/helpers/language/libraries)
- themes (default)
- vendor

Codeigniter uses routes via Router.php to map urls so the url looks clean, this means instead of using:

[www.example.com/app/controllers/index.php](http://www.example.com/app/controllers/index.php)

you just use

[www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)

and so on for the other folders, but codeigniter it's object oriented, and this website is made in procedural style.

Is there a way I can reply that routes for my website?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of PHP routers plugins that you could use, among populars [AltoRouter](https://altorouter.com/), [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), [Klein.php](https://github.com/klein/klein.php).